# Activar y desactivar concepto utilizando PHP PDO

Tags: php, pdo

Soy novato y puedo tardar en aprender PDO php desde 0, Bueno este es el concepto para activar y desactivar la categoría. ¿Alguien me puede ayudar con esto? Me gustaría actualizar el estado de la categoría, el estado debe ser 0(desactivar) o 1(activar) para ocultar(hide) y mostrar(show), cómo hacer activar y desactivar el estado de la categoría?

Aquí está la estructura de la tabla

```
-------------------------------------------
| category table                          |
-------------------------------------------
| cid | cname | clink | cparent | cstatus |
-------------------------------------------
```

index.php

```
public function Category()
    {

        $db = getBD();
        $sql = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM category WHERE cparent = 0");
        $sql->execute();
        $data = $sql->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

        $menu = array();

        foreach ($data as $categ) {

            $sql = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM category WHERE cparent = '".$categ['cid']."'");
            $sql->execute();
            $sdata = $sql->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

            $categ['subcategorias'] = array();

            foreach ($sdata as $subcateg) {
                $categ['subcategorias'][] = $subcateg;
            }
            $menu[] = $categ;

        }
        return $menu;

        //AQUI UPDATE STATUS
        $status = $_GET['cstatus'];
        $sql = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM category WHERE cid = '".$status."'");
        $sql->execute();
        $data = $sql->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

        //AQUI UPDATE STATUS
        $status_var=$row->status;
        if($status_var=='0')
        {
            $status_state=1;
        }
        else
        {
            $status_state=0;
        }
            $sql = $db->prepare("UPDATE category set cstatus='".$status_state."' WHERE cid='".$status."'");

            if($sql)
            {
                header("Location:index.php");
            }
    }
```

category.php

```
$object = new myObject();    
$data = '<table>
             <tr>
             <th>Id</th>
             <th>Categoria</th>
             <th>Sub Categoria</th>
             <th>Link</th>
             <th>Estado</th>
             <th>Editar</th>
             <th>Delete</th>
             </tr>';

    $menus = $object->cCategory();

    if($menus)
    {

        foreach ($menus as $menu) {

            $status = $menu['cstatus'];
            if($status == '0'){
                ?>
                <a href="category.php?status=<?php echo $menu['cid']; ?>" onclick="return confirm('Activate');"> Deactivate </a>
                <?php
            } 
            else if($status == '1')
            {
            ?>
                <a href="category.php?status=<?php echo $menu['cid']; ?>" onclick="return confirm('Desactivate');"> Activate </a>

            <?php
            }
            $data .= '<tr>
                    <td>' . $menu['cid'] . '</td>
                    <td>' . $menu['cname'] . '</td>
                    <td>' . $menu['cparent'] . '</td>
                    <td>' . $menu['clink'] . '</td>
                    <td>' . $menu['cstatus'] . '</td>

                    <td>
                        <button onclick="GetUserDetails(' . $menu['cid'] . ')" class="btn btn-warning">Update</button>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <button onclick="DeleteUser(' . $menu['cid'] . ')" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</button>
                    </td>
                </tr>';

        }
    } else {
        $data .= '<tr><td colspan="6">No hay resultado</td></tr>';
    }

    $data .= '</table>';

    echo $data;
```

Comment: Category es el método de una clase? No entiendo adonde se instancia. Tampoco se entiende en qué parte incluyes category.php. Se carga directo en el navegador? ¿Qué es $object?

Comment: @amenadiel
Index.php es el método de una clase para funciones y interface category.php. logica $object = new Object();

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La verdad es que tu clase es un poco confusa, y aun que sólo muestras un método de la clase `myObject` parece que lo agrupa todo en una amalgama de cosas.

Lo primero que deberías hacer es es estructurar mejor la clase y separar las cosas.

Por ejemplo:

```
<?php
class Category 
{
    public function __construct ( ) 
    {
        // Cosas que se hacen al instancia el objeto
    }

    public function index ( )
    {
        // Retornar un Array con todas las categorias
    }

    public function edit ($idCategory)
    {
        // Retornas un Array con los datos de la categoría seleccionada para poder editarlos
    }

    public function update ($idCategory, $dataCategory)
    {
        // Actualizas los datos en la base de datos de la categoría editada
    }

    // Otros métodos 
}
?>
```

Luego fuera de la clase es donde debes armar el html/vista

Vista index categoria

```
<?php
include 'Category.class.php';

$objCategory = new Category;

$arrayAllCategory = $objCategory->index();

foreach ( $arrayAllCategory as $keyCat => $ValueCat )
{ 
    // Armas la tabla
}
```

Vista edit categoria

```
<?php 
include 'Category.class.php';

$objCategory = new Category;

$arrayCategory = $objCategory->edit($_GET['idCategory']);

// Formulario edición con los datos de $arrayCategory
// este formulario apuntará al archivo que hará el update
```

Vista update

```
<?php
include 'Category.class.php';

$objCategory = new Category;

 if ( $objCategory->update($id, $data) )
 { 
     // se ha actualizado
 }
 else
 { 
     // error, no se ha actualizado 
 }
```

El método de update puede ser algo así

```
<?php

public function update ($idCategory, $dataCategory)
{
    // datos para recuperar conexion o establecerla

    // actualizar registro 
    $prepare = $db->prepare("UPDATE category set cstatus= :data WHERE cid= :cid");
    $param  = array( ':data' => $dataCategory, ':cid' => $idCagory);
    if ( $prepare->execute( $param ) )
    { 
        return true; // Se actualizó
    }
    else
    { 
        return false; // No se actualizo
    }

}
```

Aparte de todo esto la forma en la que prepararas las sentencias es errónea

```
$sql = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM category WHERE cid = '".$status."'");
//                                               Aquí-> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
// Debería quedar algo asi por ejemoplo
$sql = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM category WHERE cid = :status ");
```

No se deben incrustar valores en la preparación de la sentencia, esto es peligroso y te expone a injección SQL, la sentencia se debe preparar con **:identificadores** o con **?**, los parámetros son pasados después.

[Documentación PDO prepare](http://php.net/manual/es/pdo.prepare.php)